# Converting a C string to individual integers

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c-strings, atoi

This exercise asks to take a input as a character array of number then add up the digits of the number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    //Input a series of single digit numbers
    char numbers[] = "a";

    cout << "Input a series of single digit numbers." << endl;
    cin >> numbers;

    //convert the character array into a int array.
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += atoi(numbers[i]);
    }
    cout << "Sum of digits: " << sum; 

    return 0;
}
```

The atoi function, by my understanding, converts only whole character arrays (C strings) at a time, and I guess I cant step through the array, but it seems like this should work. My other option was to convert the Cstring to one large integer, then use the length of the string to step through and calculate the digits in each position but that's probably more inefficient that I could be making it.

What would you use to find single digits as ints for a character array?

Comment: `numbers` will be a `char[2]`. You can't expect to capture more than single digit numbers into `numbers`. `size` is also undefined in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char numbers[] = "a";
```

This creates an array of 2 `char` items. That's not sufficient for anything reasonable. Use a `std::string` instead.

```
cin >> numbers;
```

Better use `std::getline` from the `<string>` header.

```
sum += atoi(numbers[i]);
```

`atoi` takes a string as argument, not a single `char`. You want the sum of the digits, not the sum of the number values you get by applying `atoi` to all right substrings of the specification.

For a digit character `ch`, the corresponding digit value is `ch - '0'`.